# show dataset sorted by time to upload

Tags: ckan

I have to show/publish on "CKAN page" more than one datasets sorted by YEAR.
I have a metadata named YEAR and values are (for e.g) 2015 or 2016 or 2017 and so on.

Every year I upload new dataset end I'd like to have them sorted as: the first is 2017 and the second is 2016 and so on.

There is a kind of way, throug configuration or parameter where I can modify thi option? Or I need to check in the code Python (and which part)?

Thanks
Cheers

Answer (score 0):

You should read these **[docs](https://docs.ckan.org/en/2.8/extensions/adding-custom-fields.html#sorting-by-custom-fields-on-the-dataset-search-page)**. They explain adding custom sort options for dataset search results page with an example.

The default sort order is by most recently updated as well. So from the sounds of things, this may give you the result you're after if you upload once a year. But is not guaranteed if you update older datasets in the meantime.

Also, I'm guessing this was down voted as you don't mention what you've tried such as example code, what you've tried reading or looking up on your own, etc.

Here is some info on [asking good questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking) for the future.